# Angular2. Не запускается метод в app.component.ts

Tags: angularjs, angular2, typescript

Только начинаю разбираться в TypeScript и Angular2. Пишу первый компонент и наткнулся на проблему, которую не удалось решить гуглением.

Ошибку создаёт вызов метода `setDateArray`. Без него всё отрабатывает нормально. Вызываю его в `ngOnInit`, но пробовал и в `constructor`. Ошибка в консоли такая:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 
> 'AppModule'.
>
> Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
> at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
> at eval (compiler.js:15282)
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15264)
> at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34398)
> at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34359)
> at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34253)
> at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
> at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5561)
> at eval (main.ts:11)
> ```

Привожу код. Вырезал всё, не относящееся к вопросу:
app.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanvasSettings } from './canvas-settings';
    import { Rate } from './rate';
    import { RateService } from './rates.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
        providers: [RateService]
    })

    export class DatePoint() {
        X: number;
        Y: number;
        cost: number;
        diff: number;
    }

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        title = 'Exchange Rate via Canvas';
        bgrdCanvas = new CanvasSettings("bgrdCanvas");
        interactiveCanvas = new CanvasSettings("iaCanvas");
        rates: Rate[];
        dateArray: DatePoint[][][];
        sampleProperty: number;

        constructor(private _rateService: RateService){}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.getRates();
            this.setDateArray();
            console.log(this.dateArray);
            console.log(this.rates);
        }

        getRates() {
            this._rateService.getRates().then(rates => this.rates = rates);
        }

        setDateArray() {
            this.sampleProperty = 8;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле есть объявление двух классов, `DatePoint`:

> ```
> export class DatePoint() {
> ```

и `AppComponent`:

> ```
> export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
> ```

и ещё есть аннотация [`@Component`](https://angular.io/api/core/Component):

> ```
> @Component({
>     selector: 'app-root',
>     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
>     providers: [RateService]
> })
> ```

Вот только аннотация применяется к классу, который непосредственно следует за аннотацией, поэтому, как минимум, надо перенести аннотации к тому классу, для которого она предназначена:

```
export class DatePoint() {
    ...
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [RateService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Да, всё заработало. Спасибо.